8.44.0.FINAL or 9.44.0.FINAL which one is officially latest
9.44.0.FINAL is not listed as the final version in https://www.drools.org/
However, the mvnrepository.com has the 9.44.0.FINAL listed.
8.44.0.FINAL or 9.44.FINAL, which one is production ready release?
I tried both 8.44.0.FINAL and 9.44.0.FINAL but just wanted to make sure I use the production ready version.

All of the FINAL versions are production-ready. (As opposed to the RC's, betas, etc.)
Whether you use something in the 8.x release train or the 9.x release train will depend on your requirements and what functionality you're looking to support. Read the release notes for each version to inform your decision.
